# xbindkeys does not bind xdotool key command for a key

Tags: ubuntu, xdotool, xbindkeys

I add the `xdotool` commands to `.xbindkeysrc`. The commands for mouse work, such as

```
"xdotool mousemove 200 200"
  q
```

but I keys do not work, such as

```
"xdotool key x"
  q
```

What can be the reason that the first command works perfectly, but the second command not. When pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> key, instead of typing <kbd>X</kbd>, it does nothing (it just prevernts the default behaviour of <kbd>Q</kbd> key).

Mouse to key commands also work, such as

```
"xdotool key x"
  b:8
```

The problem is not the `xdotool` command, as the following command works in the terminal

```
xdotool key x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
xdotool sleep 0.2 key x
```

I'm not sure why it seems related to timing, but perhaps due to the overhead of, in my case, xbindkeys calling `sh` or `bash` and `wmctrl`.

Comment: Definitely something strange going on with the timing. Even with the `sleep 0.2`, you have to hit the keys just right to get it to work.